# how to pass an unknown size Array to sql statement in groovy.sql.Sql

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

I want to create a simple query using [Groovy sql](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) and pass a list of ids to it which has unknown size.
example:
this works fine

```java
List<Long> userIds = sql.rows('SELECT id FROM users').collect { it.id }
```

but how can I pass userIds and find schools

```java
List<Long> schoolIds = sql.rows('SELECT id FROM school WHERE id IN (?)', userIds).collect { it.id }
```

and this does not work.

Comment: It may depend on your database.  For example, I think Postgres supports `ANY(?)`. Which database dialect(s) do you need to support?

Comment: You may also use (with positive side effect) **only one query**: `SELECT id FROM school WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM users)`

Answer (score 1):

for generic db this should work if `userIds` list is not very large

```
def query = 'SELECT id FROM school WHERE id IN (' + userIds.collect{'?'}.join(',') + ')'
sql.rows(query, userIds)
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. any Idea for how to do it without extra string creation? because the ids might be a very big list

Comment: what's your database server? it's specific to each db. and if it's very long list then think about different query like `select * from B where A_ID in ( select A_ID from A )`. there is no reason to get large list from db and send it back to db...